# Kotlin Unwrapping Function Compiler Error

Tags: kotlin

Anyone know why the following code doesn't work?

```
private fun wrapLogIfNeeded(buildMessageOnCurrentThread: Boolean, log: () -> String): () -> String
  return if(buildMessageOnCurrentThread) {
    val message = log() // Type mismatch: Required () -> String Found: Unit
    { message }
  }
  else {
     log
  }
}
```

But this does:

```
private fun wrapLogIfNeeded(buildMessageOnCurrentThread: Boolean, log: () -> String): () -> String
  return if(buildMessageOnCurrentThread) {
    val message = lazy { log() }.value
    { message }
  }
  else {
     log
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of the syntax ambiguity:

```
val message = log()
{ message }
```

This code gets parsed as if it was `val message = log() { message }`, that is, `log` called with the lambda `{ message }` as its argument. And the statement `val message = ...` has type `Unit`, hence the error message.

To resolve it, you can add a semicolon:

```
val message = log();
{ message }
```

Comment: As an alternative to a semicolon, you can replace the lambda `{ message }` with an [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions): `fun() = message`.